# Cocos2d change the direction after collision

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-physics

I want change the direction of CCSprite when collide with polygon shape CCSprite.  How to detect the angle of collision when two body collide or the direction in which it is going to move using Cococs2d ? TIA .
what i was using was atan2f(pair.contacts.normal.x, pair.contacts.normal.y); but not working.

Comment: are u using box2d. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function accept two parameter first y second x.

```
float angle = atan2f(b2BodyPosition2.y - b2BodyPosition1.y, b2BodyPosition2.x - b2BodyPosition1.x);
```

you can also use

```
ccpToAngle which is present in CGPointExtension.h ..
ccpToAngle(pair.contacts.normal);
```